# in_array() выдаёт разные результаты

Tags: php

Здрaвствуйте, почему `in_array()` выдаёт `true` в первом примере?

```
$array_1 = array(
    'test',
     true
);

$array_2 = array(
    'test'
);

var_dump( in_array( 'Lorem-ipsum', $array_1 ) ); // True
echo '<br>';
var_dump( in_array( 'Lorem-ipsum', $array_2 ) ); // False
```

Comment: видимо идёт нестрогое сравнение по неявному преобразованию

Comment: [**strict** Если третий параметр strict установлен в true, тогда функция in_array() также проверит соответствие типов параметра needle и соответствующего значения массива haystack](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php)

Comment: @Ипатьев спасибо, а можете сказать, почему если вместо `true` (в первом примере) поставить `123` или `false` или `null`, то результат `false`?

Comment: @caboke учите что такое неявное преобразование в PHP и к чему всему этому списку относится непустая строка

Comment: потому что для false и null надо искать пустую строку чтобы вернуло true. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/types.comparisons.php

Comment: @АлексейШиманский in_array() выполняет неявное преобразование только если в массиве встречается `true`?

Comment: @Ипатьев понятно, большое спасибо.